# What is the cause of Access Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, recursion, segmentation-fault

I was wondering what causes the segmentation fault in the following program.  I think the segmentation fault occurs during the recursion.  Once I input a number the error message "An Access Segmentation Fault occurred" appears.

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "simpio.h"

 int sum(int n);

 main()
 {
     int n, Sum;

     printf("Please enter the amount of elements in sequence n/n+1: ");
     printf("LOL1\n");
     n=GetInteger();
     Sum=sum(n);
     printf("LOL2\n");
     printf("The sum of the first %d elements of the sequence n/n+1 is: %d", n, Sum);
     printf("LOL3\n"); 
     getchar(); 
 }

 int sum(int n)
 {
     if(n=0)           return(0);
     else              return((sum(n-1))+(n/(n+1)));
 }
```

Comment: Please show your `GetInteger`.

Comment: Also, you have a bug in your sum(int n) function. You should have if(n == 0)

Comment: `n=0` --> `n==0`

Comment: Recursion without a base case can cause segfault.

Comment: @meaning-matters I think he is using visual studio or something .... and the function is defined in those libraries.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, theres no more segmentation fault, unfortunately it does not work as it is intended to, it keeps printing 0 :/

Comment: Note that `n/(n+1)` will always be 0 when using integer arithmetic, so your function will always return 0.

Comment: @Paul R but let's say n=3, then won't that mean n/(n+1) will be 3/4?

Comment: 3/4 = 0 when using integers - perhaps you should be using floating point ?

Comment: oh... right.  I forgot, sorry

Comment: [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oWDKy0sKFyQ) is what the code is from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This function:

```
int sum(int n)
{
    return (n = 0) ? 0 : (sum(n - 1)) + (n / (n + 1));
}
```

is an infinite loop, eating up stack space on each iteration until it runs out of memory.  You really mean `(n == 0)` here.  After you fix that, you'll then realize that for integers, `(n / (n + 1))` is always 0, so the function will work but always return 0.

You don't really need recursion at all here, but you do need to use something other than integers to make that division meaningful.

Comment: Thank you very much, I forgot about the division property with integers :)

Answer (score 5):

The assignment expression `(n = 0)` is never true: it is an assignment, not a comparison. That's why your recursion continues until your program overflows the stack.

You need to change `(n = 0)` for `(n == 0)` or C's idiomatic `!n`, which means the same thing.

Also note that you perform integer division: `n/(n+1)` is always zero when you use integers. You need to switch to `float` or `double` to get non-zero results.

Comment: Thank you, but now that I fix that, do you know why it keeps printing 0?

Comment: @C_Beginner_Learner Because of integer division.

Comment: I already explained in the comments above re integer arithmetic.

Comment: `n / (n + 1)` will always be 0 for integers.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Hello, I don't understand this , since its a recursive call the `sum(n-1)` will keep calling the function and the integer division `n/n+1` should not execute. Awaiting your response :)

Comment: @PHIfounder Once OP fixes the `=` vs. `==` issue, integer division will execute, and return zero.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight +1 Well , absolutely , thanks !! but I guess this is a bad practice to have multiple `return`s in a single function . ain't it?

Comment: @PHIfounder OP used to have only one return statement with a conditional expression, [up until the edit #3](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/17761489/4).

Answer (score 2):

Change (n=0) to (n==0). Use the float type instead of the int type, so that we can use the division property properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(n=0)           return(0);
```

This statement is always false, hence infinite loop hence error I suppose

As an input certain standards recommends expressions such as these

```
if(0 == n)           return(0);
```

as a way of finding coding mistakes at compile time